# How to change "Manage app" link to point to "Additional app setup"?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to publish a Marketplace app which requires additional setup after install, but I can't figure out how to change the link in the screenshots below. Basically I want to change from screenshot1 to screenshot2. The manifest docs have no mention of it either.

I've already set the Setup Url in my Google Apps SDK console page.

screenshot1:
[image]

screenshot2:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the Setup URL in your project should trigger that automatically. Please ensure your project settings were updated.

**Update:** Upon further investigation, the dialog only shows the "Additional app setup" link when the install is done from the Google Apps Admin console. When the installation is done from the standalone page or the "Integrate with Google" button "Manage app" link is shown instead. However, in those cases clicking on "Launch app" button will take the administrator to the Setup URL if one is configured.

Comment: But (presumably) the second screenshot is a real screenshot.

Comment: Yes, project settings with Setup URL are saved. Does it matter if the app is unlisted (as I am in the process of testing the setup)?